# Qt WebEngine capture network package

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am porting my Qt app from Webkit to WebEngine. In my Webkit code, I use **QNetworkAccessManager** to capture network packages. But in WebEngine, document say:

> Qt WebEngine Does Not Interact with QNetworkAccessManager

So I can't do that in my WebEngine code.

This is my Webkit code:

```
......
reply = QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(
        manager, operation, req, data)

def _on_replyfinish():
    data = reply.peek(reply.bytesAvailable()).data()
    cookies = manager.cookieJar().mozillaCookies()
    self.resopnseHistroylist.append({
            'reply': reply,
            'url': req.url().toString(),
            'host': req.url().host(),
            'filename': req.url().fileName(),
            'body': data,
            'code': reply.attribute(QNetworkRequest.HttpStatusCodeAttribute),
            'request_header': get_headers(req),
            'cookies': cookies,
            'response_header': get_headers(reply),
            'time': int(time.time()*1000),
        })

reply.readyRead.connect(_on_replyfinish)

......
```

I use PyQt5.8 and Qt5.8.

I can [capture network package using Qt WebEngine Developer Tools](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-debugging.html), but I want to do that in code like Webkit does.

Is there any other way to apture network packages in WebEngine like in Webkit?

Comment: Why do you need to capture them exactly, i.e. what's your goal?

Comment: @The Compiler, our team use WebEngine to crawl some websites and we want to capture them as log message.

Comment: A [QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html) is probably the closest you can get to that.

Comment: @ The Compiler,   QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor don't meet our needs. I think may be I should tell my leader we can't do that in WebEngine.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/annulen/webkit/wiki then.

Comment: @TheCompiler Thanks for your answer. Maybe our team don't need WebEngine. I will try https://github.com/annulen/webkit .